# How can I customize the 'fn' (aka. function key)?

Tags: keyboard, function-keys

Is it possible to customize the `Fn` (aka. function key)? For example, I can press `Fn` + `I` to trigger the ↑ (uparrow key).

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 on a dell inspiron 16 7610.

Comment: Try using Actiona: https://wiki.actiona.tools/doku.php?id=en:start

Comment: I have a Corsair K55 keyboard here where you can modify what the FN key does, but it would have to be changed to a modifier that the OS can see like Left_Ctrl, etc. in order for something like this to work. You also need the software from Corsair to change this as it cannot be done at the OS level without it. I don't know if Dell has a program for their keyboard,  but looks like it can only be a `Fn` key.  https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/en-us/inspiron-16-7610-laptop/inspiron-7610-setup-and-specifications/keyboard-shortcuts?guid=guid-a72a2f9f-012c-437f-9774-c5263480dda5&lang=en-us

Answer (score 5):

Disappointing answers are also answers. Here, the answer is no: the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key is seen only by your hardware to modify the effect of other keys, but it is not seen by the operating system, hence you cannot reconfigure it.

Run the `xev` utility. It shows information about input events. When you hit the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key, no output is produced - this key does not make it into the operating system.

Comment: vanadium, there are ways to do it.

Comment: @RishonJR it is possible if the OS is the one that changes the behavior of the keys when <kbd>Fn</kbd> is pressed. In my situation, the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key is tied only to the keyboard's firmware and the only purpose of it is changing the RGB lights of my keyboard.

Comment: @RishonJR My `Fn` key only works with certain key combos and none are tied into the OS itself.  The OS doesn't even recognize my `Fn` key presses at all.  If you do have an answer showing how you can make the OS see the `Fn` key, please write it up.

Comment: @RishonJR Feel free to answer. I will be glad to delete my answer if something better comes up.

Comment: Okay Thanks :) .